# WhereSelectEnumerableIterator to data table c#

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have linq query that I don't know to how get values from cells
for instance how I get sum of totalt for specific group
or how can I convert result to a datatable?
thanks in advance

```
var result = from tab in dtLines.AsEnumerable()
             group tab by tab["GoodsRef"]
             into groupDt
             select new
             {
                 Group = groupDt.Key,
                 PriceP = groupDt.Sum((r) => decimal.Parse(r["PriceP"].ToString())),
                 TotalT = groupDt.Sum((r) => decimal.Parse(r["TotalT"].ToString()))
             };
```

Comment: Why does it need to be a datatable? You have a perfectly good query right there.

Comment: Emm.I'm new to linq,how can i get cell value?like get sum of specific product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve whatever you like from `result` just like this:

```
// TotalT for a group: GoodsRef == "Electrical Goods"
var x = result.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Group == "Electrical Goods").TotalT;

// Some of all TotalT
var totalSum = result.Sum(t => t.TotalT);
```